# Is there was way to limit the number of queries from youtube api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube-data-api

I am creating a tampermonkey script that will read a line of text that contains an artist and song title from a webpage and will create a link that will open a new tab to the first result that is returned from the youtube api. My issue is that when the page is loaded and say there are 5 songs on this particular page, according to my youtube api dashboard, I am making about 1200 api requests for that single page. Im guessing that its because when I query a single artist/song, its getting every result on its server. I tried limiting my maxResults to 1, but this doesn't help. Since youtube decreased the number of queries a single API gets, I would like to know if there is a way to reduce the number of queries it makes. Realistically, I just need the first result from the GET request, since chances are that will be the correct video.

here is a snippet of my code that parses through the json data:

```
function getLink(artist, song){

    // API Key
    var key = "MY_KEY";

    // Setup url for api
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=' + artist + "-" + song + '&maxResults=1&key=' + key;

    // call api and get videoId
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open("GET", url, false);
    xhReq.send(null);
    var id = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);

    return id.items[0].id.videoId;
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `maxResults:1` with `maxResults=1`

Comment: Just changed it and tested and it is still pulling about a thousand queries for 7 searches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm looking at the same Google doc, but it says the **part** parameter should be **snippet** for a [Search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) call. I know different calls take up different quota amounts. Using the query below I get only one song returned. It seems to use only the normal 100 units of quota required for Search:list:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=Adele+Hello&fields=items(id(videoId))&key=API_key`

It returns:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "YQHsXMglC9A"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped a lot. I didn't realize that Search:list uses 100 units. I restructured my code so that it only queries when the user clicked the link and I'm now getting 170 queries per request which is a lot better!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to escape `artist` and `title` with something like `encodeURIComponent`. It could be that the strings in those variables are breaking the intended URL you want to process.

Even more, if you do a test with the Youtube API sandbox, you could check it by yourself. In my case I've tried "Radiohead" and "Paranoid Android" with 3 max results and it's working fine. [See here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=es-419&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22id%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A3%2C%22q%22%3A%22Radiohead-Paranoid%20Android%22%7D&apix=true)

Comment: Yeah, so I can inspect it with chrome developer tools and I see that it is only returning 1 item in the json, but its still showing that its submitting a ton of queries. I just put both artist and song in encodeURIComponent and it looks like its still pulling a ton of queries.

Comment: Well, maybe the problem is that your code is triggering the method several times and not only when you actually want it.

I've made a local test and it just triggers once...

Comment: I changed my code so that it only queries when the link is clicked and not query everything on the loading of the page and now i'm down to 170. I thought 1 youtube query = 1 unit, but it turns out it is 100 units. Thank you

Comment: Clearly is something related to it. Vote me up if it worth the help ;)